# Command 'getent'

Tags: bash, mac-osx, passwd, zsh

**Part 1**

Is `getent` supposed to be an executable?

In my zsh setup, I can see getent is actually defined as a function

```
$ which getent   
getent () {
    if [[ $2 = <-> ]]
    then
        grep ":$2:[^:]*$" /etc/$1
    else
        grep "^$2:" /etc/$1
    fi
}
```

If I want to execute it from bash shell,

```
bash -c  "getent passwd user"
```

I get a `getent: command not found` error.

**Part 2**

In Mac OSX, `getent` fails regardless if the user id is valid or not. It turns out the user id is not kept in the `/etc/passwd` file. Why it is so? And what is the alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On linux, Solaris and (I believe) *BSD systems getent is an executable and will consult the same set of databases as normal lookup functions (/etc files, LDAP, NIS etc).

Os-x doesn't provide getent but you can get similar functionality using the `dscacheutil` or `dsutil` programs (which talk to the directory services back end). A web search for "osx getent" will give you more details.

Answer (score -1):

getent AND dsutil fail for me as well on OSX bash.

As Paul points out above, this command dscacheutil will work. I was able to get the specific user verified with this command:

```
dscacheutil -q user -a name <username>.
```

A list of users with this command

```
dscacheutil -q user | grep 'name:'
```

Comment: I've removed about half this post as it had nothing to do with the question. If you have a question about using `!` in a `grep` command, you need to post it separately by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. (Or don't, you can find the answer [here](https://superuser.com/q/133780/144961).)